# Image of the product of a Matrix and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix, is it necessarily true that $\text{im}(A)=\text{im}(AA^T)$ where $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$.

Comment: If you place \$ dollar signs \$ around your math, it'll format it. $im(A) = im(AA^T)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following holds for matrices with real entries.

We first claim that $\ker(AA^T)=\ker(A^T)$. Indeed, if $v\in\ker(AA^T)$, then$$\langle AA^Tv,v\rangle=0$$yields$$\langle A^Tv,A^Tv\rangle=0,$$and hence$$A^Tv=0.$$It now follows that $rank(AA^T)=rank(A^T)=rank(A).$ Since clearly $im(AA^T)\subset im(A),$ we obtain the desired equality.

Comment: Could you explain what $\langle AA^Tv,v\rangle=0$ and $\langle A^Tv,A^Tv\rangle=0$ mean? I am unfamiliar with the concept and notation

Comment: It's just the standard inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$.